# Sql update with single query

Tags: mysql

This question is asked by my friend. He faced this question during an interview. Please forget about db structure :), I think they asked this question to check logic :)

Here is the scenario. There is a hotel with different floors and different room numbers in each room.

Initially table will be like this;

```
Floor Rooms
1
1
1
2
2
```

Rooms column will have null values

We need to fill as shown  below using a single query. Is this possible? If so how we can do that. Please advice.

```
Floor    Rooms
1        101
1        102  
1        103
2        201
2        202
```

Comment: You can do this using cursor , joining two tables .  but before that you need to have the structure

Comment: Do you want to do this in a single step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query if you're looking for a **true atomic** solution without having to set and reset session variables outside of your update query:

```
UPDATE floor_rooms
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT floor, (@room := 0), (@floor := 0)
            FROM floor_rooms
            WHERE ISNULL(room)
    ) AS floors
    ON floor_rooms.floor = floors.floor
    SET floor_rooms.room =
        IF(@floor = floor_rooms.floor, @room := (@room + 1), @room := 1)
        + (@floor := floor_rooms.floor) * 100;
```

DEMO @ [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/caa82/1)

Answer (score 1):

Very simple,Code for SQL Server,

```
with cte as
(
select * 
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by  fno order by fno) as rowNo
 from hotel
 )
 update cte set rNo = fno*100 + rowNo
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a122f/1)**

Code of MySQL, I was able to select only, for update Temp table should be used, I am new to MYSQL.

```
set @type = 1;
set @num  = 0;

select fno,(fno*100) + row_number as newRommNo  from
(
select * 
,@num := if(@type = fno, @num + 1, 1) as row_number
,@type :=fno
 from hotel
) as a
```

**[DEMO OF MYSQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c73f2a/25)**

Comment: second floor is start by 201 not 204

Comment: There's no `over` clause in MySQL, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
update tablename set `Rooms`=(Floor*100)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is may be help for you

we must declare `scalar` variable:

```
SELECT fno, CASE WHEN fno = 1 THEN fno * 100 +@rooms :=@rooms + 1 
WHEN fno = 2 THEN fno * 100 +@room :=@room + 1 END FROM hotel, 
(SELECT @rooms := 0) AS w1, (SELECT @room := 0) AS w2
```

here demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54c0d/1